# How to force indentation of first paragraph in classicthesis?

Tags: indentation, classicthesis

When using the package classicthesis, the first paragraph of each section has no indentation.

How can I force the indentation of the first paragraph?

Comment: Have you tried with the [`indentfirst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) package?

Comment: Yes, it changes nothing.

Comment: That is the design decision made by the template author.

Comment: I know. How can I change that without changing classicthesis.sty?

Comment: @Trump Can you please add a minimal example? The code in the given answer works for me also with the `scrbook` or `scrreprt` classes.

Comment: It works with indentfirst. I don't know why it failed the first time I have tried.

Comment: @Johannes_B Isn't  this the normal behavior of many standard classes (article, report, scrreprt)? I don't think classicthesis sets this at all.

Comment: @philip I assumed it was about paragraph indentation in general since it was stated that indentfirst does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indentfirst` package works for me:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis,indentfirst}


\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the title}

\section{Rabbit}
Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant 

Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow ElephantMouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant Mouse Cat Rat Tommy Cow Elephant

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make use of packages like `blindtext` or `lipsum`.